JWT token is expiration issue
I am using JWT Authentication in one of my application along with Spring Boot/Security and its my first take on JWT.
Following are my set and get authentication methods:
@Component
public class JwtService {

    private final String SECRET_KEY = "eaeb7fefd93b6a53da9dd86b6b228e1f8a13f355b57279141093d6c63c29f4e0";

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(username, claims);
    }

    private String createToken(String username, Map<String, Object> claims) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60))
                .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    private Key getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    // extract the username from the token
    public String extractUserName(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(getSignKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    // to check expiration of token
    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    // to check token is expired or not
    public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUserName(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

Previously the JWT is generated and received in headers just fine. However, after writing the extract code for getting username from token when I am trying to login using credentials, getting this below error
JWT expired 13729211 milliseconds ago at 2024-07-07T14:41:48.000Z. Current time: 2024-07-07T18:30:37.211Z. Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.

The exception says allowed clock skew is 0 milliseconds. In my above code EXPIRATIONTIME is set to 1hour (I believe this is set in seconds). I have tried increasing this value too but I still get the error.
Please suggest what am I doing wrong ?
I try to debug this using some log statement checking the expiration date and time but as I am learning this first time, I don't have much knowledge on this.

According to your code this token is nearly 4 hours expired.  Are you renewing or getting a new token as needed?

Could it be a different time zone and you lack utc compensation?
